# How to use old method of setting rootViewController in AppDelegate using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios13, xcode11

I just started a new project of iOS. I created the project using xcode 11 and iOS 13. When I created project i found out that in order to set our own rootController we have to use sceneDelegate instead of AppDelegate. I want to ask if there is any possibility to use old method of setting rootControllers in AppDelegate instead of using sceneDelegate.

```
 import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    var window : UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let loginController: HomeViewController = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)

       //        let navController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginController)
               self.window?.rootViewController = loginController
               self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a seperate nib file for your `HomeViewController `or its in `Main.Stroyboard`?

Comment: @KeshuR. its a separate nib for homeviewcontroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to use AppDelegate and opt-out for SceneDelegate

1. Go to Info.plist and remove **Application Scene Manifest** entry from Info.plist.
2. Remove SceneDelegate.swift
3. Add `var window: UIWindow?` in your AppDelegate.swift file
4. Delete the UISceneSession Lifecycle code from AppDelegate.swift

   ```
   import UIKit

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


   var window : UIWindow?

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let loginController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
   }
   }
   ```

Make sure to give "HomeViewController" storyboardID to your view controller.

This is how your AppDelegate.swift file should look now. You are good to go!

Comment: I followed you steps but it shows black screen now.

Comment: have you set the root view controller?

Comment: yes I have set rootController

Comment: @hussnainahmad Also delete `UISceneSession Lifecycle` methods from `AppDelegate.swift`

Comment: i also deleted that but still black screen

Comment: @hussnainahmad Do you see any error in console?

Comment: @hussnainahmad i just tried it. created a new project and followed the above steps. and everything works fine. I have also updated the answer

Comment: @KeshuR. I just edited my question please check my appDelegate

Comment: @KeshuR. i am not using storyBoard i am using nib for my homeViewController

Comment: If you are not using storyboard, then you need to remove "Main storyboard file base name" from your plist.

Comment: @hussnainahmad remove "Main storyboard file base name" from your plist

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use sceneDelegate then you can remove all sceneDelegate and also remove 'Application Scene Manifest' from info.plist

set `UIWindow` variable

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Make sure you have removed `Application Scene Manifest` this from `info.plist` and change the background colour of your view controller.

Your device's `Dark Mode` is enable if you want to remove dark mode from app add this key into your `info.plist`

```
User Interface Style = Light
```

Comment: i did that but it shows. black screen now.

Comment: your device set dark mode right? remove the dark mode else change the colour of your view controller @hussnainahmad

Comment: No i am using a simulator. and i think its not on dark mode

Comment: Ok check this also Application Scene Manifest. i have created new project and follow all step it's working

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `SceneDelegate`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
            guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
           //Make sure to do this else you won't get 
           //the windowScene object using UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            self.window?.windowScene = windowScene 
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
            window?.rootViewController = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Comment: because we have a pattern to follow in our app. that pattern is forced by our company